# IdentityServer client example to remember QueryString parameters after redirect

Tags: asp.net, openid-connect, identityserver4

When unauthenticated user opens URL of secure page on the client web site, he/she redirects to IdentifyServer for login and after successful login returns to the main page of the client(when using default implementation of client/IdentityServer).
Question on github [RedirectUris with callback params does not work](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1371)  explains that it is a client responsibility to remember QueryString and has the recommendation:

> If you need to maintain state across the redirects, then issue a
>   cookie client side or pass data via the official state param. You
>   generally want to use the state parameter as a pointer to locally
>   persisted data - e.g. a cookie. Create a cookie with a random name -
>   store whatever needs to be stored there - round trip the cookie name
>   as the state parameter. Just putting data on state has the issue that
>   someone could potentially modify the values on the way back.

The question [Identity server 3 MVC client state parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953762/identity-server-3-mvc-client-state-parameter) has similar recommendation:

> Store state in your app about the redirect path you want after login.
>   After IdSvr logs your user in and redirect back to your one well-known
>   callback URI you then read that state to know where to send the user.
>   IOW, keep track of that in store state in your app about the redirect
>   path you want after login. If you put it in the ProtocolMessage.State
>   , then be aware that someone can tamper with it. If you protect the
>   state (sign/encrypt), then it's ok. It might be easier/safer to keep
>   that state in your app.

As it is a very typical scenario, I hope that someone has an example of such implementation. **Can anyone share the sample code/give a reference to some article?**

More info about my particular scenario:

My client is web forms site with implementation similar to [IdentityServer3.Samples WebFormsClient](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient).
1.User opens `https://mydomain/mypage?querystringparams`
2.In Web.config I have

```
  <authorization>
           <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

3.In client Startup.cs the relevant setting

```
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
   Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",//IdentityServer4 Host
   RedirectUri ="https://mydomain/"
}
```

4.On IdentityServer the relevant settings

```
new Client
{
     RedirectUris = { "https://mydomain/" , "http://mydomain/" }
}
```

5. After login user redirected to `https://mydomain/` , but needs to be redirected to `https://mydomain/mypage?querystringparams`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked into WebFormsClient. But if you could use `OpenIdConnectAuthentication` Owin middleware (used in OwinClient example) redirection should happen automatically. If OWIN middleware is not supported you can handle it manually. Have a look at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcCodeFlowClientManual sample. There you can take control of the state parameter and handle redirection yourself.

e.g:
In `AccountController/SignIn()` you can get `redirectUri` from the query string and add that to the state parameter sent to identity server's `authorization endpoint`.

Then in `AccountController/SignInCallback()` you can retrieve the state parameter and redirect the user to the URL that he entered.

With OwinAuthentication middleware this should be handled automatically.